# I try to assign the existed string and integer to the arrays but it keep saying core dumped

Tags: c, cs50

I already knew there is something wrong within the for loop, but I can't see why it doesn't assign the string already existed to the array. I just started learning coding. Any help is much appreciated!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int count;
}
people;

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    //the number of candidates is (argc - 1)
    int grossnumber = argc - 1;
    people candidate [grossnumber];

    for (int n =1; n <= grossnumber; n++)
    {
        **candidate[n].name = argv[n];
        candidate[n].count = 0;**
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays are zero-base indexed in C. Consider that when deducing how you can set up the range for `n` to enumerate. Ex: one proper range is `n=0; n<grossnumber; ++n`, and the code inside accesses `candidate[n]` and  `argv[n+1]`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not use `**` to mark lines in your code. That changes the syntax of your code. Instead just add normal comments like `// <<< this line` or similar.

Comment: Please explain what you expect this to do `**candidate[n].name = argv[n];`. How many levels of pointer to pointer are involved? Are there any pointers which you attempt to dereference with the two `**`. In case Gerhard is right, please use `/* comments */`.